# PyQt4 Buttons but only one works. Why?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have made an application using pyqt4.

It has seven buttons. Six are exactly the same, but just the last one works. 
The other one is the exit button

Each button run a script who transforms a csv file in some ESRI SHP file.

Where is the error ?

```
import sys
from archivo import *

import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp 
import csv  
import tkinter.filedialog



class importo_script_py (QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx01, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx01)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx02, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx02)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx03, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx03)


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonT3, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.boyaT3)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonTOSCA12, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.boyaTOSCA12)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonT14, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.boya14)


    def boyaxxx01(self):
        #sasemar1
        boya ='http://XXXXXXXX.csv'
        if not os.path.exists('C:\Export\SASEMAR01'):
            os.makedirs('C:\Export\SASEMAR01')

        df = pd.read_csv(boya, sep=',', names=['boya', 'cod_boya', 'y', 'x', 'time_stamp'])
        out_file = 'C:/Export/SASEMAR01/sasemar1'
        y = df['y'].astype(float).tolist()
        x = df['x'].astype(float).tolist()
        date = df['time_stamp'].tolist()
        w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
        w.autoBalance = 1  #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
        w.field('longitud-x', 'F', 10, 5)
        w.field('latitud-y', 'F', 10, 5)  #float - needed for coordinates
        w.field('DATE_TIME', 'C', 35)
        for j, k in enumerate(x):
            w.point(k, y[j])  #write the geometry
            w.record(k, y[j], date[j])  #write the attributes
        prj = open(out_file + '.prj', 'w')
        proyeccion = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
        prj.write(proyeccion)
        prj.close()
        w.save(out_file)

    def boyaXXX2(self):

        boya= 'http://xxxx.csv'

        if not os.path.exists('C:\Export\SASEMAR02'):
            os.makedirs('C:\Export\SASEMAR02')
        df = pd.read_csv(boya, sep=',', names=['boya', 'cod_boya', 'y', 'x', 'time_stamp'])
        out_file = 'C:/Export/SASEMAR02/sasemar2'
        y = df['y'].astype(float).tolist()
        x = df['x'].astype(float).tolist()
        date = df['time_stamp'].tolist()
        w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
        w.autoBalance = 1  #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
        w.field('longitud-x', 'F', 10, 5)
        w.field('latitud-y', 'F', 10, 5)  #float - needed for coordinates
        w.field('DATE_TIME', 'C', 35)
        for j, k in enumerate(x):
            w.point(k, y[j])  #write the geometry
            w.record(k, y[j], date[j])  #write the attributes
        prj = open(out_file + '.prj', 'w')
        proyeccion = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
        prj.write(proyeccion)
        prj.close()
        w.save(out_file)
```

.....
.....

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = boyasTodas()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's not the way `__init__` works.

Comment: This is the .pyw file  I am working on windows

Comment: You should only have one __init__ definition in your class. Right now, each subsequent __init__ will replace the existing one, which is why only the last one is actually used.

Comment: I Am amazed anything worked at all...

Answer (score 2):

maybe this works:

```
class importo_script_py (QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx01, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx01)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx02, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx02)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonxxxx03, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.xxxx03)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonT3, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.boyaT3)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonTOSCA12, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.boyaTOSCA12)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonT14, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') 

    etc....
```

Oh, and `etc...` does not mean more inits; it means the rest of your class methods.

`__init__` is the python constructor for a class. It will be executed once when the class is created. What you are doing here is declaring `__init__` multiple times so you are effectively overwriting your previous `__init__`'s. Only the last one is executed and that would be the button that was working.

Oh, and please take a look at [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) python style guide, because your (class) naming is horrible.

Comment: This will work, but please explain to the OP why he can only have one `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `__init__` per class. Every time the interpreter sees an `__init__` it is replacing the definition with the new one, ie. only the last `__init__` is going to do something

Comment: 'because your (class) naming is horrible'
You are right   I´ll try to resolve it